# tor installation

Tags: kali-linux

im trying to install TOR in my kali lunix but im getting this error
root@Lunix:~# apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate.

Comment: Kali Linux is not a general purpose distribution, so please read this first: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/173368

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwIOj6-IofA ?

Answer (score -3):

Kali Linux **is not** a Linux distro **for normal things** like **Web-Browsing** and such. **The APT package manager is also not meant to work on Kali and has no support, community, etc.**, even though it's based on Debian. Kali is meant for **penetration testing** and **security auditing**. Check this out for more info: https://docs.kali.org/introduction/what-is-kali-linux

So I would **recommend** you to get a distro like **[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)** if you mainly want to access the **Tor Network**.